# MSYSGIT BASH : Execute SQL against MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, bash, msys

I'm running MSYSGIT on Windows and I want to be able to execute SQL statements against a SQL server directly from the bash console and bash scripts.  Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it?  Thanks!

Comment: I change the tag to msys from msysgit since this really doesn't apply to git itself - Msys provides the bash prompt, not msysgit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)